# How to implement uint32 addition and subtraction operations in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hex, unsigned, unsigned-integer, uint32

Please do not suggest using any gems or creating classes for unsigned integers.

Input data - strings that represent 4 byte sequence.
Output data should be the same type of string.

This is what I've got so far:

```
def addition(augend, addend)
    sum = augend.to_i(16)+addend.to_i(16)
    sum -= 2**32 if sum >= 2**32
    sum = "%08X" % sum
    return(sum)
end

def subtraction(minuend, subtrahend)
    difference = 0

    # Some magic here.

    difference = "%08X" % difference
    return(difference)
end

puts addition('FFFFFFFF', '00000002')       # 00000001
puts addition('B1B0AFBA', 'FEEE302D')       # B09EDFE7

puts subtraction('00000055', '00000005')    # 00000000, expected 00000050
puts subtraction('B1B0AFBA', 'FEEE302D')    # 00000000, expected B2C27F8D
```

How should `subtraction()` be implemented? And could `addition()` be improved?

Comment: "Please do not suggest using any gems or creating classes for unsigned integers." – Why? Not re-inventing the wheel is one of the most basic skills of any good programmer. And Ruby is an OO language, you cannot do *anything* without using objects, and classes are the way to create objects. You ask about improving `addition`, and the most important improvement I can see, would be to make it a method of an appropriate object.

Comment: @JörgWMittag agree, although re-inventing bicycle might be a valuable experience in some cases. I asked not to suggest using objects or gems for 2 reasons. First, to help anyone who will be seeking an algorithm for this (say for Lua, which got no support for objects). Second, I personally need to do such calculation only once, so using gem or objects would be irrational in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just do opposite of addition.  Also in ruby last line of method is returned and no need to reassign variable on last line since it's eval will be returned.

```
def subtraction(minuend, subtrahend)
  difference = minuend.to_i(16) - subtrahend.to_i(16)
  difference += 2**32 if difference < 0
  "%08X" % difference
end
```

Performance seems fine:

```
puts Benchmark.measure{ 1000.times {subtraction('B1B0AFBA', 'FEEE302D')} }
#=>  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.001853)
```

Since these methods are only different by 3 characters I thought, "why not try some meta programming to dry it up?":

```
subber = lambda {|str, a, b, c| str.gsub('A', a).gsub('B', b).gsub('C', c)}

meth_def = <<EOF
  n = arg1.to_i(16) A arg2.to_i(16)
  n B= 2**32 if n C= 2**32
  "%08X" % n
EOF

define_method(:addition){|arg1, arg2| eval subber.call(meth_def, '+','-', '>')}
define_method(:subtraction){|arg1, arg2| eval subber.call(meth_def, '-','+', '<')}
```

This could probably be DRYed up more but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm aware of that using `return()` is unnecessary, that's just my style of organazing code. Very interesting idea of using meta programming here. But I'm afraid that `subtraction()` doesn't work correctly, not yet. Also could you please rename variables used in `subtraction()` method to those names given in the question. And one more question: is there a way to make lines `2` and `3` in the method more compact?

Comment: I get the same answer you posted as expected answer in subtraction.  Other than that I have done no other testing.  In answer to your question in making lines 2/3 any more concise, I tried but it was actually adding overhead when I benchmarked it.

Comment: Sorry for editing your own answer, but I’m glad that you have approved the edit. You haven’t tested your code when no overflow should be happening, e.g. `subtraction('00000055', '00000005')` would perform incorrectly. Could you also modify meta programming, I mean the check for overflow.

Comment: @IanStapletonCordasco your explanation why you have rejected the edit is completely illogical.

Comment: @ IanStapletonCordasco I'm not sure which edit you're referring to, it may have been an accident.

Comment: Another user did reject my edit, after that you have accepted it. The meta section is still incorrect I believe. Check the signs.

Comment: @MOPO3OB what should the signs be in the meta part?

Comment: Checks for overflow are `if sum >= 2**32` and `if difference < 0`.

Comment: @MOPO3OB Is the logic in my subtraction method correct?  If so, I think the meta does what it's supposed to.

Comment: I have modified that logic in the method. Compare it’s check for overflowing with meta.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167443/discussion-between-lacostenycoder-and-mopo3ob).